# Submit a page, check fields name being submitted, examine response

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to get data from a web application. I dont have access to database or the source of the app(.net).

The web app works like this -- enter values in fields, click submit button, and the data associated with these fields are returned in a modal popup.

I need to do the same programatically, without actually opening the browser.

I need to know the name of the fields that need to be posted, and the URL. And then store the response.

Any .Net language would do.

Any clue how it can be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use these functions to post a page ang get result:

```
public static string HttpPost(string url, object[] postData, string saveTo = "")
{
    StringBuilder post = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < postData.Length; i += 2)
        post.Append(string.Format("{0}{1}={2}", i == 0 ? "" : "&", postData[i], postData[i + 1]));
    return HttpPost(url, post.ToString(), saveTo);
}
public static string HttpPost(string url, string postData, string saveTo = "")
{
    postData = postData.Replace("\r\n", "");
    try
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
        byte[] send = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        req.ContentLength = send.Length;

        Stream sout = req.GetRequestStream();
        sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
        sout.Flush();
        sout.Close();

        WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
        string returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveTo))
            File.WriteAllText(saveTo, returnvalue);

        //Debug.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}", postData, returnvalue);
        return returnvalue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("POST Error on {0}\n  {1}", url, ex.Message);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Macro for the very detailed reply! It works nicely for the most part. However, I still have a problem. On the web page, it is an AJAX post back, the results are shown in a modal popup. Now with your code,  I am getting the response, whole of the page, but the modal popup is wrong. I am supplying an array of string to your function with textboxname, value, dropdownlistname, value, ... etc. What am I doing wrong? :-(

Comment: @Supars: you're doing nothing wrong, the function I provided should be used exactly as you're doing. Probably the page is doing something strange I don't know, sorry :(